# Change Base URL in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

I 'm trying to change the base URL `http://myscreenclass.com/` to `http://myscreenclass.com/home`. I changed the .env file and updated the config/app.php file as well. I tried to solve the issue many different ways, but nothing happens.

How can I change the URL?

Comment: run `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to redirect people from `myscreenclass.com/` to `myscreenclass.com/home` so that page is the default page when trying to view the homepage?

Comment: Yes I am trying to redirect @NathanHeffley

Comment: I left an answer that should help explain what's going wrong with your setup. If you provide more information on what routes you have I could help you even more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I am trying to change base URL http://myscreenclass.com/ to [http://myscreenclass.com/home](http://myscreenclass.com/home_)*

May I suggest reading up on [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#redirect-routes) with Laravel? You can achieve this by adding this to your web routes file.

```
Route::redirect('/', '/home');
```

Comment: It answers the question he asked @NathanHeffley . I'll edit the answer if they edit their question to something different.

Comment: How it will differentiate Route::get('/home') and Route::post('/post') using redirect