# How can I change www.website.com to www.website.com/myFolder/ root url in laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

How can I change **www.website.com** to **www.website.com/myFolder/** root path?

So anytime I redirect to any URL I want my root path **www.website.com/myFolder/** to stay unchanged in Laravel 5.7

Comment: Hey @Aman , I wrote an answer to a very similar question for changing your base URL. [Should check it out here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601852/change-base-url-in-laravel-5-5/53602054#53602054)

Comment: It doesn't work for post redirect

Comment: Move the laravel installation and then use the web servers redirects where they don't match /myFolder to /myFolder?