# Named Routes not used app base url in laravel App

Tags: laravel, routes

## My setup

I set in app URL in `.env`:

```
APP_URL=http://local.task-app.com
```

I have one route:

```
Route::get('/login/callback',
'LoginController@teamwork')->name('loginCallback');
```

I get API route with the following:

```
$callbackUrl = route('loginCallback');

// This returns http://local.task-app.com/login/ as expected.
```

---

## What I'm trying to do:

***I want to update Base App URL***

---

I *updated* .env

```
APP_URL=http://local.review-app.com
```

I reference the `$callbackUrl` in the same fashion:

```
$callbackUrl = route('loginCallback');
```

**What's happening:**

It's still returning `http://local.task-app.com/login/callback`. The url is not updating to the most recent .env change.

Comment: the `APP_URL` is only used for the console since there is no incoming request that is defining the host. the host your site is on is determined by the incoming request when used with a webserver ... this is why we can have domain/subdomain routing ... if this is a web request the APP_URL has no effect

Comment: did you clear the configuration cache ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes i did configuration cache clear

Comment: Try running the following commands: `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:cache`, and `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Hey @Ajay - I posted an answer to something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601852/change-base-url-in-laravel-5-5/53602054#53602054). That sort of what you're looking for?

Comment: @rkg i did everyone